# convergence for the weak-* topology

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let E be a Banach space.

Let $(x^∗_n )$ be a sequence in $E^∗$ verifying $(<x^∗_n , x>)$ converges for any $x ∈ E$.

Prove that $\exists x^∗ ∈ E^∗: (x^∗_n )$ converges vers $x^*$ for the weak-∗ topology.

The solution I have states that it is a corollary of the Banach Steinhaus theorem but I don't see how it is related and I am not aware of such a corollary.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What do u mean $<x_n^*,x>$ ?

Comment: $E^*$ is the topological dual of $E$, so by  $<x_n^*,x>$ I mean $x_n(x)$ as $x_n^*\in E^*$

Comment: You know of the Uniform Boundedness Principle ?

Comment: Yes it is another name of Banach Steinhaus theorem, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here's how you go about it.

Your condition says $ x_n^*(x)$ is convergent and in particular bounded for any $x \in E$

So the uniform Boundedness Principle gives you $$ sup_n ||x_n^*|| <\infty$$ .

Now if you define $$x^* :E \rightarrow \mathbb K $$
$$ x\mapsto lim_n \ x_n^*(x)$$ then this map is bounded since $ ||x^*(x) || \leq sup_n ||x_n^*|| $

Also $x_n^* \rightarrow x^* $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ by definition of $weak^*$ topology.

Comment: Thank you! I just don't see why the map is bounded? Could you please explain why $||x^*(x) || \leq sup_n ||x_n^*||$? I know that $||x^*(x) || \le sup_n ||x_n^*(x)||$ but I don't see how you get  $sup_n ||x_n^*(x)|| \le sup_n ||x_n^*|| $. By using Holder we get $||x_n^*(x)|| \le ||x_n^*||||x||\le sup_n ||x_n^*||||x||$ but still we need to get rid of ||x||$?

Comment: No $||x^*|| = sup _{||x||\leq 1} |x^*(x)|$

Comment: Thank you !that makes sense!